# Rounding the corners of a View in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have this *View* in Kotlin:

```
<View
android:id="@+id/DotView"
android:layout_width="6.5dp"
android:layout_height="6.5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
/>
```

and I need to round the corners since it is a *Dot* and I have been investigating and testing how I can do it to round the corners but I just can't find the answer.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create a drawable shape xml file and set background property of the view to the drawable file!

res/drawable/circle.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

res/drawable/rounded.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

and set background to view like this :

```
<View
android:id="@+id/DotView"
android:layout_width="6.5dp"
android:layout_height="6.5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/rounded"
/>
```

Comment: it worked for me, thanks!